# Live Video Scrubbing on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, video

The standard movie player in Media Foundation doesn't seem to support very fluid scrubbing. I'd like to make it so that video being shown refreshes constantly as you slide your finger across the bar, rather than jumping every few seconds as it does by default. At first I thought the default controls might have had some kind of delay built into them, but using my own slider to set the playback time didn't help. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm still experimenting, and it looks like there is a set interval between possible scrub start points. Maybe there's some way to decrease the interval.

Comment: Not possible when used in conjunction with formats like H264 - make sure you understand the basics of video compression (i-frames vs. p-frames).

Comment: Can you clarify? Is there a format I CAN use?

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm looking for the sam answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. I grab a frame from a video asset on slide change. See code below. It's cut from my current project an might contains som errors but you will get the idea. It's in Swift 1 though hope that's ok.

```
var urlVideo :NSURL = NSURL()
var vidLength :CMTime = CMTime()
var durInSeconds: Float = 0.00
var timescale:CMTimeScale = CMTimeScale()
var videoInfo:NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
var chosePosSlider:UISlider = UISlider()

@IBOutlet weak var imgCont: UIImageView!

func generateThumnail(url : NSURL, fromTime:Float64) -> UIImage {

    var asset :AVAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(url) as! AVAsset
    var assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)

    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
    assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;

    var error       : NSError? = nil
    var time        : CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(fromTime, timescale)
    var img         : CGImageRef = assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil, error: &error)
    var frameImg    : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: img)!

    return frameImg

}

func sliderValueDidChange(sender:UISlider!) {

    var newTime:Float = durInSeconds * sender.value
    setFrame(newTime)

}

func setFrame(pos:Float) {
    imgCont.image = generateThumnail(urlVideo, fromTime: Float64(pos))
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    videoInfo = info as NSDictionary
    urlVideo = videoInfo.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL) as! NSURL

    var asset :AVAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(urlVideo) as! AVAsset

    vidLength = asset.duration
    durInSeconds = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(vidLength))
    timescale = vidLength.timescale

    chosePosSlider = UISlider(frame:CGRectMake(20, 450, 340, 20))
    chosePosSlider.minimumValue = 0
    chosePosSlider.maximumValue = 1
    chosePosSlider.continuous = true
    chosePosSlider.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    chosePosSlider.value = 0
    chosePosSlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(chosePosSlider)


    setFrame(0.0)

}
```

Comment: I'm not working on this project any more, but if anyone can confirm that this works in swift, I'll mark it as a valid answer. Upvoting anyway.

Comment: `var time : CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(fromTime, timescale)` fromTime should be something like `timescale * fromTime` - at least when I tested this.

Comment: So I got this to work but it's a little choppy, works both ways equally as quick but could be smoother. Is yours completely smooth?